# Find ignored unit tests which are correct

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have big project and many ignored unit tests. Is there any way that I can run all ignored tests using surefire maven plugin and see list of passed tests? 
Total number of ignored tests are >1000, so, manually it is impossible.

Comment: Are they marked with `@Ignore`  annotation or they ignored otherwise?

Comment: @khmarbaise with `@Ignore` annotation.

Comment: Than you need to write a script which will remove the annotation and record the names of the tests...

Comment: @khmarbaise oh, I thought surefire can do it without scripting:)

Comment: This might be a good idea to improvement maven-surefire ? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE

Comment: Did you found a way? I am interested in this topic as well.