# Run all test cases and ignore @ignore annotation in junit

Tags: java, maven, junit

To reduce the manual efforts of removing @ignore annotation from all the test cases, than running all the test cases and again adding **@ignore** to test cases.

Is there any way to disable @ignore annotation throughout all the test cases during project build and run **all test cases**.

Comment: Why do you ignore them anyway? It might be better to use testgroups instead and annotate special test with a special group. If junit doesn't support groups, then you could use testng instead.

Comment: **-1-** In maven normally one runs the unit tests first, but this can be skipped.  _This seems what you are asking for._ **-2-** Statistics on the `@ignore`d unit tests are feasible (annotation scan), and probably exist out there.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29470155/1240557 (can't flag as the other one doesn't have an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @ignore

is a valid way in Java to ignore certain methods, but I think it's a bad idea. The danger behind this is that it can make you're code a bit clumsy. In some time your whole test case code is full of @ignore and test cases might be forgotten. ( in my experience ). You can do it, but I think it's dangerous. :)

A better idea ( and it takes a little more time ), is to make a manual rule to condition. Worked great for me! See this link:
http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/

Comment: How does the manual rule improve over the @ignore annotation?